# Microphone input gets -120.0 dB after call interruption

Tags: iphone, ios4

(this is my first question so i hope i give enough information)
i am developing an application that samples the microphone input continuously with a timer.
during normal operation everything is ok, if i close the app with the home button and then return to it i may see a few iterations with microphone input of -120.0 but then it start measuring correctly again.

however if i place a call to the phone (and not answer) the microphone input measures -120.0 all the time.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set an audio session with an audio session interrupt handler.  Then you can cleanly stop and restart your audio queue or audio unit (etc.) after the call interruption in the handler callbacks.  See Apple's Audio Session documentation.

Comment: thanks, i get the beginInterruption and the endInterruptionWithFlags when i place a call but anything i do inside doesnt seem to help, i tried setting the audio session active to NO an when the interruption ends back to YES, i tried setting up my mic input again and many shots in the dark, but after the app resumes i keep getting -120dB (or an exception if i do something wrong)...

Comment: What happens when you stop recording without an interruption but while your app is running?

Comment: the app continuously updates the measure from the mic:                 "- (void)levelTimerCallback:(NSTimer *)timer { 
 
 [micInput updateMeters];

 NSLog(@"Avg. Power 0: %f", [micInput averagePowerForChannel:0]);
 
 NSString *newText = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"%f", [micInput averagePowerForChannel:0]];
..."   so usually the numbers make sense, only after the interruption i get always -120.0 dB

Comment: If you can't stop, you app won't work after an interruption.  Add a way to stop.

Comment: i managed to resolve the issue! i saw somewhere a way to use NSZombieEnabled and i understood that my mic input audioRecorder wasn't retained, i retained it and after the interruption i reset the parameters and it works!, thank you for your help!!